# how to merge different line in multiple files using terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

i have two files(a.txt ,  b.txt)

a.txt

```
boy
girl
grade
test_1
test_2
```

b.txt

```
boy
girl
grade
test_3
test_4
```

now i want to merge this two files(c.txt)

c.txt

```
boy
girl
grade
test_1
test_2
test_3
test_4
```

friends please help me!
**terminal command**

Comment: The question is: is the first section of a.txt *always* b.txt? (i.o.w. is b an extended version af a)?

Comment: You'll notice that answerers are having to guess what you mean. Please try to write clearer questions.

Comment: As mentioned, the question simply is unclear; is the section after *grade* possibly overlapping, does sorting matter,  etc etc. please take the effort to make a proper question, guessing is not what we do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq > c.txt
```

Note that, this can work for more than 2 files, in general, the following with concatenate the contents of file1, file2, ....., fileN into outputFile :

```
cat file1 file2 file2 file4 .... fileN | sort | uniq > outputFile
```

Comment: I think you should leave away the `-c` switch, as this will count the number of occurrences of each line.

Comment: Yes, well sported @the_Seppi . I have since removed, thanks.

Comment: There is no need for a `sort | uniq`. `sort -u` should be enough.

Comment: And why the `cat` commands?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order of the lines doesn't have to be preserved (in this specific case the order of the lines will be preserved, but it may well not happen in other cases, since the files will be merged into a single file, the single file will be sorted and its non-unique lines will be discarded), using `sort`:

```
sort -u a.txt b.txt >c.txt
```

- `-u`: prints only unique lines.

```
% cat a.txt
boy
girl
grade
test_1
test_2
% cat b.txt
boy
girl
grade
test_3
test_4
% sort -u a.txt b.txt >c.txt
% cat c.txt
boy
girl
grade
test_1
test_2
test_3
test_4
```